# Is there a reason r functions wouldn't accept the "or" logical operator?

Tags: r, logical-operators

I'm struggling to see why the "or" operator won't work for me with the filter function.

```
filter(year == 1960 || 2010)
```

I'm not running into an error the function simply doesn't do anything when I run this.

Comment: `||` is for *single* comparisons, `|` is for vectorized comparisons

Answer (score 6):

In `R` we can use either `%in%`

```
library(dplyr)
filter(df1, year %in% c(1960, 2010))
#similar to syntax in `python`
#df1.query('year in [1960, 2010]')
```

or

```
filter(df1, (year == 1960) | (year == 2010))
#similar to syntax in `python`
#df1.query('year == [1960, 2010]')
```

Comment: ...and to add, the original code "*doesn't do anything*" because `df$year == 1960 || 2010` is interpreted something similar to `c(FALSE,TRUE) || TRUE` which returns `TRUE`, which in turn selects every row.